# Issue with installing anki on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, anki

I installed anki on my Ubuntu 14.10 machine with no errors (using `dpkg -i`). When I run it as a normal user I get following error.

```
~/software$ anki
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/anki", line 5, in <module>
    import aqt
  File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import optparse
  File "/opt/epd/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 418, in <module>
    _builtin_cvt = { "int" : (_parse_int, _("integer")),
  File "/opt/epd/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 566, in gettext
    return dgettext(_current_domain, message)
  File "/opt/epd/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 530, in dgettext
    codeset=_localecodesets.get(domain))
  File "/opt/epd/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 465, in translation
    mofiles = find(domain, localedir, languages, all=1)
  File "/opt/epd/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 428, in find
    val = os.environ.get(envar)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'environ'
```

However, when I run it as root (using `sudo`) it works fine with no errors. I would prefer to not run it as root. How can I go about diagnosing this?

Comment: I think you need root permission to do what you want thus its impossible otherwise

Comment: It may be that root has a search path different from your user, and therefore runs a different instance of python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates that you're loading a module called `os` that *doesn't* contain environ.

This shouldn't be the case if you are loading the usual `os` module.

Check where this faulty `os` module is coming from.

You may try running anki with `python -v` and inspect the output